# Questions about selecting one cell by using multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-operator, calculation

Say I have the pandas DataFrame below:

```
       A      B      C   D
    0  foo    one    2   0
    1  foo    two    2   0
    2  foo    three  2   0
    4  bar    one    2   1
    5  bar    two    2   1
    6  bar    three  2   1
```

I want to do some calculation, and the values in column C are not always the same, I want to get the values below by using conditional selection.

I want to get Value of C (when B=ONE & A=foo)
This is the code I tried by gave me error `KeyError: C`

```
df.loc[(df["A"] == 'foo') & (df["B"] == 'one'), "C"]
```

In addition, if the value for C is a constant value but I don't want to assign it to 2 directly, I still want to refer it to the dataframe, if the value changes I can get different output, what's the best way to assign this value? (A bit struggled with this since it's a bit wired to add conditions here if it's a constant value)

Can someone help me thanks.

Comment: did you try `df["C"].loc[...]` ?

Comment: `df[(df["A"] == 'foo') & (df["B"] == 'one')]['C']`

Comment: @CeliusStingher not working, still get the same error..

Comment: @furas  not working, still get the same error..

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: create minimal working code so we could run it. When I get your data with my code then it works without problem. Maybe problem is in totally different place. Maybe your column has different name then `"C"` - it may have spaces ie. `"C "`

Comment: BTW: your version also works for me - you must have problem with column's name.

Comment: yes I got an extra space in the column name, very hard to spot, thank you @furas